# How to solve 3 equations over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations, smith-normal-form

I have those 3 equations: 
$$-5x+2y+4z+w=8\\ 27x+10y+2z+7w=6\\ -20x-6y-4w=-10$$

I tried to solve them over $\mathbb{Z}$ via making a matrix at $SNF$ (Smith Normal Form), So I began with this matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-5 & 2 & 4 & 1\\
27 & 10 & 2 & 7\\
-20 & -6 & 0 & -4
\end{bmatrix}$$

And what I get is this (after many calculations):

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

But when I trying to solve via this, I get:

- $x=\frac 8 1=8 $
- $y = \frac 6 {2}=3$
- $z=\frac {-10}{2} =-5$
  (Because we learn that we need to divide $x$ by $d_1$, $y$ by $d_2$ and so on...)

Now it's wrong because I can fit any $w$ for this solution.
Can you help me please and tell me where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, so can you give me just obe solution for example? because I cant find one... @PeterForeman

Comment: @PeterForeman, but can you explain me please how do you get it?

Comment: @CS1 You just type the equations into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5x%2B2y%2B4z%2Bw%3D8+and+27x%2B10y%2B2z%2B7w%3D6+and+-20x-6y-4w%3D-10)...

Comment: First, change the last equation to $10x+3y+2w=5$ as an initial implification.

Comment: @PeterForeman - Yes, but I need the way :-) not only the final solution...

Comment: @saulspatz, what do you mean? I don't understand...

Comment: Do you know how to set up the augmented matrix? $$\begin{bmatrix}-5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & | & 8 \\
27 & 10 & 2 & 7 1 & | & 6 \\
-20 & -6 & 0 & -4  1 & | &  -10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: And do you know how to then put this augmented matrix into Smith Normal Form?

Comment: Once you've done that, there's still some further steps, but if you cannot get that far then it's hard to know what to say to you.

Comment: @LeeMosher - If I replacing lines - I need to do it also for the solutions?

Comment: @LeeMosher, of course I know - I just didn't now if I need to put the left column (8,6,-10) at the SNF matrix...

Comment: Well, after seeing Brian Fitzpatrick's answer, I guess I was confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wish to solve the system $Ax=b$ over $\Bbb Z$ where 
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-5 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
27 & 10 & 2 & 7 \\
-20 & -6 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right] & b&=\left[\begin{array}{r}
8 \\
6 \\
-10
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
To do so, consider the Smith form 
$$
\overset{U}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{A}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-5 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
27 & 10 & 2 & 7 \\
-20 & -6 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{V}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -8 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & -2 & 12 & 1
\end{array}\right]}=\overset{D}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0
\end{array}\right]}
$$
Here, $U$ and $V$ are *unimodular*, which means that $U$ and $V$ are invertible over $\Bbb Z$.

Now, note that $Ax=b$ is $UAVV^{-1}x=Ub$ which reduces to $DV^{-1}x=Ub$. So, we can solve our system by first solving $Dy=Ub$ for $y$ and then taking $x=Vy$.

The system $Dy=Ub$ is
$$
\overset{D}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{y}{\left[\begin{array}{r}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\
y_{3} \\
y_{4}
\end{array}\right]}
=
\overset{Ub}{\left[\begin{array}{r}
8 \\
22 \\
-6
\end{array}\right]}
$$
This gives $y=\langle 8, 11, -1, y_4\rangle$.

Finally, we have $x=Vy$ which gives
$$
x=\left[\begin{array}{r}
y_{4} \\
-4 \, y_{4} + 19 \\
3 \, y_{4} - 1 \\
y_{4} - 26
\end{array}\right]
$$

To compute the above Smith form, consider the following operations.
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
-5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
27 & 10 & 2 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-20 & -6 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
& \to \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 4 & -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
7 & 10 & 2 & 27 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & -6 & 0 & -20 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
&\to \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & -26 & 62 & -7 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 16 & -40 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & -4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
&\to \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 16 & -40 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -4 & -26 & 62 & -7 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & -4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
&\to \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & -18 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -8 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 12 & -35 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
&\to \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -8 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 12 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: @CS1 I don't know. If you show your work, then we can point out any errors.

Comment: @CS1 I've added my smith form calculation.

Comment: I've never seen this method of calculating the Smith normal form, do you have a link to  some notes detailing it?

Comment: I don't have a reference offhand, but it is generally true that reducing $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A & I_m \\ \hline I_n & 0\end{array}\right]$ to $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} B & L \\ \hline R & 0\end{array}\right]$ by only using row operations on the "top" rows and column operations on the "left" columns gives $LAR=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first solve the system in the reals.
We get 
$$
{\bf x} = {\bf x}_{\,0}  + \lambda \;{\bf x}_{\,1}
  = \left( {\matrix{   {26}  \cr    { - 85}  \cr    {77}  \cr    0  \cr  } } \right)
 + \lambda \;\left( {\matrix{   1  \cr    { - 4}  \cr    3  \cr    1  \cr  } } \right)
$$

Now the $\gcd$ of the components of ${\bf x}_{\,1}$ is $1$, and ${\bf x}_{\,1}, \; {\bf x}_{\,2}$ are independent, 
so any integer value of $\lambda$ is a solution over $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$-5x+2y+4z+w=8 ------   (A)\\ 27x+10y+2z+7w=6 -----(B)\\ -20x-6y-4w=-10 -----(C)$

From, $[2(B)-(A)+3(C)]$ we get:  $w=(x-26)$

From, $(C)$ we get, $w=[-(y+85)/(4)]$

From, $(A)$ we get, $w=[(z-77)/(3)]$

Taking, $w=1$, we get:

$(x,y,z,w)=(27,-89,80,1)$